# Finding a non-Abelian group $G$ that satisfies the following condition

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

For my exam review, I'm trying to find a non-Abelian group $G$ so that the map $$\sigma:G \rightarrow G$$ defined by $$\sigma (a)=a^3$$ is not a homomorphism.

I know that the general linear group of $2 x 2$ matrices over $\Bbb{R}$ is non-Abelian, but is the defined mapping a homomorphism on it? If not, how would I go about showing it? If it is a homomorphism on it, can someone point me in the right direction to find such a group that satisfies this condition? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If $\sigma$ is a homomorphism, then $a^3b^3=ababab$, and thus $a^2b^2=baba$, so we just need to find any group which doesn't have that relation.

If you know about free groups, then one example is the free group on two letters, which has no relations at all. Otherwise, we just need to find a group $G$ with elements $a,b$ such that $a^2b^2\neq baba$.

It is always useful to consider symmetric groups when seeking counterexamples, since they are easy to write explicitly. If $a$ and $b$ are transpositions, then $a^2b^2=1$, so we just need find a case where $baba$ is not the identity.

Take $a=(1\ 2)$ and $b=(2\ 3)$. Then $ba=(1\ 2)(2\ 3)=(1\ 2\ 3)$ and so $baba=(1\ 3\ 2)\neq 1$.